# For loop is accepting the first object in array and ignoring others

Tags: arrays, node.js, string, mongodb, for-loop

I have created a For Loop which assigns values to users in my database.
My code consists of:-

An array called **Output** which is something like this;

`{['Number': '907384719', 'amount': 23], 
  ['Number': '907118281', 'amount': 50]}`

Then I have created a for loop which extracts the **number** and **amount** values from the **output** array;

```
var getLength = output.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < output.length; i++) {
        numbers = output[i].number;
        amount1 = output[i].amount;
}
```

In my app, I have made a query to the user's data collection to extract the ID of the users which their numbers are listed in the above **output** array.

```
var query = { number: numbers };
        db.collection("accounts").find(query).toArray(function(err, result, from, to) {
        if (err) throw err;
        for (i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {

            id = result[i]._id;
```

After getting the IDs of the users, I wanted to increment their balance with the
**amount** values listed in the **output** array;

```
 balance.findOneAndUpdate({
                userId: getObjectId(id)
            }, {
                $inc: {
                    balance: parseInt(amount1)
                }
            }, async function(err, res) {
                if (err) {
                    return callback(err)
                } else {
                    callback(null, res.value.balance)
                }
            });
```

After writting this code ***i'm facing a problem***. This script increments the balance of the chosen users, but it increments with the wrong **amount** values.

The for loop only increments the balance with the first "**amount**" value in the output array. For example by using the above array the script increment every user's balance with 23 points.

I tried a lot of things but it seems like there is something blocking my For Loop. Here is the full code, I included some comments to explain more;

```
exports.findUser = function(newData, e, callback) {

    // get the number and the amoount attached 

    var output = {
        ['Number': '907384719', 'amount': 23],
        ['Number': '907118281', 'amount': 50]
    }

    var getLength = output.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < output.length; i++) {
        numbers = output[i].number;
        amount1 = output[i].amount;

        //console.log(numbers); These two consoles seem to output the right data
        //console.log(amount1);


        var query = {
            number: numbers
        };
        db.collection("accounts").find(query).toArray(function(err, result, from, to) {
            if (err) throw err;
            for (i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
                // gets the IDs of the users with their numbers are in the "output array"
                id = result[i]._id;
                //var amount = 500;

                balance.findOneAndUpdate({
                    userId: getObjectId(id)
                }, {
                    $inc: {
                        balance: parseInt(amount1) // only increments with 23 points 
                    }
                }, async function(err, res) {
                    if (err) {
                        return callback(err)
                    } else {
                        callback(null, res.value.balance)
                    }
                });


                //console.log(id);
                //console.log(numbers); outputs only he first number
                //console.log(amount1); outputs only the first amount "23"
            }

        });

    }
}
```

My script is getting the right account to increment points to, but it increments only with the first "amount" value in the array. So please help me out on how I can increment every balance with its own amount from the `output` array.

Answer (score 0):

You're using the same `for var`  in both your for loop (var i), you need to change your second var so you can loop through all your array:

```
db.collection("accounts").find(query).toArray(function(err, result, from, to) {
            if (err) throw err;
            for (var j = 0; j < result.length; j++) {
             //rest of your code
```

Comment: thanks for the response, I tried your solution but the error is still occurring.

Comment: Did you changed `id = result[i]._id;` to `id = result[j]._id;`?,